# element.getText().then(function) not being executed

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber, bdd, angular-promise

I am working with protractor and `cucumber`. I want to print the text returned from getText. I am using .then function to obtain such text, but for some reason, `console.log` code is not being executed.

> Why is this happening?

```
checkDropdown: function (value, dropdown) {
    let name = element(by.id(dropdown));
    name.getText().then(function(text){
        console.log(text);
    });
    expect(name.getText()).to.eventually.equal(value);
},
```

The protractor.conf.js file is:
Protractor file is:

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', // This is targetting your local running instance of the selenium webdriver

specs: [
    '../Features/UI_Tests.feature'
],

capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome' // You can use any browser you want. On a CI environment you're going to want to use PhantomJS
},

framework: 'custom', //We need this line to use the cucumber framework

frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'), // Here it is

cucumberOpts: {
    //format:  'pretty',
    require: '../Features/step_definitions/my_steps.js', // This is where we'll be writing our actual tests
    //tags: ['@login','@app'],
    strict: true,
    plugin:"json"
},
resultJsonOutputFile:'./testResults.json', //output file path to store the final results in .json format
params: {
    env: {
        hostname: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000' // Whatever the address of your app is
    }
}
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the promise is rejected?

Comment: I do not know, how can I check if it is rejected?

Comment: By using [promise.catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch).

Comment: please show our protractor conf.js

Comment: You can see my protractor.conf.js file

Comment: does it go any better if you make it an async function, let name=await element..., and console.log(await name.getText()); (so no 'then') ?

Comment: also wondering if name is reserved for by.name?

Answer (score 1):

May be the text value which you log is blank.

Can you try adding some test in front of your **text**

```
 name.getText().then((text)=>{
        console.log('Text value is' + text);
 });
```

Just to check if console.log is executed.

Comment: I had already done it and nothing happens. I have also debugged the code and the console.log() is not being executed. Thanks for your answer Bharath